# How do I poll a future twice in a `fn poll_..`?

Tags: rust, async-await

I'm implementing AsyncRead for a struct, that should decompress data.

I'm using pin project and my problem is, that whenever I call `let this = self.project()`, it consumes `self` and whenever I call `this.reader.poll_read(..)` afterwards, it consumes `this.reader` so I can't poll again and I can't project again, but I need to call it multiple times, in order to discover how many bytes need to be read next.

1. just returning with Ok is not possible, because per definition if `poll_read(..)` doesn't fill at least one byte [it means EOF](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/trait.AsyncRead.html), but in our case we can't fill one byte, but need to read more bytes from the reader.
2. returning with Pending has to wake the task again, but we actually need to run it again immediately.

So I though of calling the waker and returning Pending, should run my `poll_read(..)` again.

```rust
cx.waker().wake_by_ref(); // call me again?
return Poll::Pending;
```

That actually works, but is it really the correct way?

Sample code from the `poll_read(..)`:

```rust
#[pin_project]
pub struct AsyncDecoder<R> {
    #[pin]
    reader: R,
    state: DecoderState,
}

impl<R> AsyncRead for AsyncDecoder<R> where R: AsyncRead {
    fn poll_read(
        self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        buf: &mut ReadBuf<'_>,
    ) -> Poll<io::Result<()>> {

        let this = self.project();
        // ..

        // 1. read file header (4 bytes)
        this.reader.poll_read(cx, ..)?;
        // ..

        // 2. read block header (n bytes)
        this.reader.poll_read(cx, ..)?;
        // ..

        // 3. read compressed data block (n bytes)
        this.reader.poll_read(cx, ..)?;
        // ..

        // repeat 2. + 3. until EOF
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to poll twice? If the stream is not ready, all reads will be pending, won't they?

Comment: Before `poll_read(..)` you don't know how many bytes are ready, so you just call it with a reasonable buffer that is filled as far as possible and then you maybe are in a state where you need to call it again immediately, because we need to read more. It's not pending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the waker works but adds unnecessary overhead. The way to replicate a `Pin<&mut T>` is by using [`Pin::as_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/pin/struct.Pin.html#method.as_mut):

```rust
impl<R> AsyncRead for AsyncDecoder<R>
where
    R: AsyncRead,
{
    fn poll_read(
        mut self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        buf: &mut ReadBuf<'_>,
    ) -> Poll<io::Result<()>> {
        // let this = self.project();
        // ..

        // 1. read file header (4 bytes)
        self.as_mut().project().reader.poll_read(cx, ...)?;
        // ..

        // 2. read block header (n bytes)
        self.as_mut().project().reader.poll_read(cx, ...)?;
        // ..

        // 3. read compressed data block (n bytes)
        self.project().reader.poll_read(cx, ...)?;
        // ..

        // repeat 2. + 3. until EOF
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think that's the best option, as the documentation says: `as_mut()` "[...] This method is useful when doing multiple calls to functions that consume the pinned type."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be fine.

An async runtime has to support the `cx` being woken before a poller returning, because the `cx` may have been sent to another thread that will have no idea whether or not the  original thread has returned or not.

Comment: I marked the `Pin::as_mut()` post as solution, because that's what the documentation recommends and obviously better performance. Thank you for your input as well.